# why rowCount() php function Calculate deleted items?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, rowcount

i use rowCount() php function to get number of my PDO query. but the issue is that this function Calculate deleted items from database.

i want to get number of exist items in DB without deleted items.

tanks

Comment: from php doc 

    PDOStatement::rowCount — Returns the number of rows affected by the last SQL statement   http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: Limit your query with a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you mean and show a minimal example which demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PDOStatement::rowCount` is meant to count the rows affected by DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE queries.

If you want to get the number of rows returned by a SELECT query, then you can do it with a `SELECT COUNT(*)` statement. No need to use `rowCount` at all.

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php):

> For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the
>   number of rows affected by a SELECT statement.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot delete rows and get their remaining number in a single query. Make another query like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name`.